# Is there an easy way to convert a json-encoded array into a php array of json-encoded objects?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a json string similar to

```
{
  {
    "field": value,
    "other_field": value,
    "object field": {
      "field": stuff
    }
  },
  {
    "field": value,
    "other_field": value,
    "object field": {
      "field": stuff
    }
  }
}
```

and I need to convert it into an array of json strings, so each element of the output array is similar to

```
{
  "field": value,
  "other_field": value,
  "object field": {
    "field": stuff
  }
}
```

I know there's `json_decode()`, but that will turn the entire thing into a bunch of nested arrays, but I only want to do that to the top level.  Is there an easy way to do this, or am I better off decoding the whole string and re-encoding each element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode the json string, then encode each array element:

```
 $arr = json_decode($json);
 $res = array();
 foreach ($arr as $entry) {
     $res[] = json_encode($entry);
 }
```

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do this. It seems very inefficient, but it's probably better than writing a custom parser to do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode( $json )[0]` to get the first array element. Does this satisfy what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to rethink what you're doing because it's fishy. Here's one solution to what you're asking though:

```
<?php

$json = '[ {"foo": 1, "bar": true}, {"foo": 2, "bar": false} ]';
array_map('json_encode', json_decode($json));

// Array
// (
//     [0] => {"foo":1,"bar":true}
//     [1] => {"foo":2,"bar":false}
// )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's fishy about this. Can you elaborate?

Comment: The fishy thing is what you commented on @SirDarius' answer. It's doing a useless parse on the members of the array.